# Update VBScript to work with Windows 7

Tags: vbscript

I am currently running windows XP Pro on my domain computers and in the process of migrating to Windows 7.

I have a schedule task that runs a VB script at login that assigns a partition to the current user.

Here is a breakdown of the setup,

```
   -80 GB hard drive
   -30 GB system partition
   -10 GB partition (DMW Drive)
   -10 GB partition (DTH Drive) 
   -10 GB partition (NMW Drive)
   -10 GB partition (NTH Drive)
```

The script assigns the correct drive according to the time of the login.   We use this to have a storage place for users to have full access to save their data.

This runs perfectly on XP but does not run on Windows 7.

Here is the script.

```
set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    iReturn = WshShell.Run("Diskpart.exe /s removeall.txt", 1, True)
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LocalTime", , 48)
For Each objItem In colItems
    DayOfWeek = objItem.DayOfWeek
    HourOfDay = objItem.Hour
Next
    If DayOfWeek = 1 Or DayOfWeek = 3 Then
        If HourOfDay >= 6 And HourOfDay <= 13 Then
            iReturn = WshShell.Run("Diskpart.exe /s Aset.txt", 1, True)
        End If
        If HourOfDay >= 15 And HourOfDay <= 22 Then
            iReturn = WshShell.Run("Diskpart.exe /s Cset.txt", 1, True)
        End If
    End If
    If DayOfWeek = 2 Or DayOfWeek = 4 Then
        If HourOfDay >= 6 And HourOfDay <= 13 Then
            iReturn = WshShell.Run("Diskpart.exe /s Bset.txt", 1, True)
        End If
        If HourOfDay >= 15 And HourOfDay <= 22 Then
            iReturn = WshShell.Run("Diskpart.exe /s Dset.txt", 1, True)
        End If
    End If
```

Here are the text files that the script calls on.

```
ASet.txt = select volume 2
       assign
BSet.txt = select volume 3
       assign
CSet.txt = select volume 4
       assign
DSet.txt = select volume 5
       assign

Removeall.txt = 
              select volume 2
              remove noerr
              select volume 3
              remove noerr
              select volume 4
              remove noerr
              select volume 5
              remove noerr
```

Any input will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since diskpart requires elevation, you need to configure the scheduled task to run elevated ("Run with highest privileges" on the General tab of task properties).

Comment: i tried that option but the script starts to run but just doesnt assign the correct drives

Comment: Check the exit code and redirect the output to see if it sheds any light. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: i just added some information that may help as well and thank you for all you assistance with this,   confusing why it works so nice with XP then suddenly not with 7

Comment: i got it working.    thanks for your replies.   found out the script needs to have an path to the diskpart executable within the script in order to run